# How to delete a file in laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm using laravel 4 and I need to change an uploaded image, I have it in:

```
Public
--uploads
---news
----id_news.jpg
```

When editing the new's I want to make a change image form, but how could I delete and upload another file. I am using:

```
Input::file('img')->move('uploads/news', $id.'_news.jpg');
```

The problem it's that it doesn't work, it's not replacing the file, so how could I delete The image so I could upload again.

In laravel 3 I only used:

```
File::delete('path/to/file');
```

But I don't see anything about removing files in laravel docs.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is still the delete method in Laravel 4:
[src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/b9d329bc9ba5bf16ebfe98451099f371553a53f5/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php#L112)

otherwise just use good old `unlink()`!?

Answer (score 43):

I think you should append public_path() to file names , to get real file path, like this

```
File::delete(public_path().$id.'_news.jpg');
```

Answer (score 8):

You can easily do something like:

```
$filename = public_path().'/uploads/foo.bar';

if (File::exists($filename)) {
    File::delete($filename);
}
```

Reference: [Laravel-recipes Delete a File](http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/133)

Comment: You don't have to check if the file exists before deleting it. You might however want to check that it doesn't exist after you deleted it as errors are silently ignored.

Comment: Then you could add an `else` to the code above! Which means checking if the file exists always comes handy!

Answer (score 2):

Other delete usage:

```
// Delete a single file
File::delete($filename);

// Delete multiple files
File::delete($file1, $file2, $file3);

// Delete an array of files
$files = array($file1, $file2);
File::delete($files);
```

[Source: http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/133/deleting-a-file](http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/133/deleting-a-file)

Answer (score 0):

```php
$destinationPath = 'uploads/my-image.jpeg'; // from public/

if ( File::exists($destinationPath) ) {
  File::delete($destinationPath);
}
```

Comment: $destinationPath='uploads/';   where you file is stored  File::exists() check file present or not if true it simply deleted

Answer (score -2):

This works on laravel 4.2.

```
File::delete(storage_path()."/ProductSalesReport-20150316.csv");

// Here are some other paths to directories laravel offers, Hope this
   helps

/* Path to the 'app' folder */
echo app_path();

/* Path to the project's root folder */
echo base_path();

/* Path to the 'public' folder */
echo public_path();

/* Path to the 'app/storage' folder */
echo storage_path();
```